# Hover while hover function working

Tags: jquery

While my div is sliding down or up if I move the mouse on that same div, the hover effect happens a second time (or even more), how do I make if the function is now working it shouldn't restart till I take the mouse away and hover again?
    ​

```
<div id="hover">Hover on me<div id="hidden">You hovered!!</div></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#hover').show();
$('#hidden').hide();    
$('#hover').hover(function () {
    $('#hidden').slideDown(100);
    }, function () {
        $('#hidden').slideUp(100);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should use jQuery `.stop()`** ([API](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)) See the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DWZQ7/9/).

What you want to do is change your hover function slighty.

Add in `.stop()`

```
$('#hover').hover(
    function () {
        $('#hidden').slideDown(100);
    }, function () {
        $('#hidden').stop().slideUp(100);
    }
);
```

Comment: Both have the same problem not worth fighting.... They dont go fully down if I take away the mouse while its sliding down

Comment: @csh That is because the div stretches all the way across the jsfiddle window. If you move your mouse outside the box or down enough it works

Comment: @csh I updated my answer with a new jsfiddle showing the div more clearly

Comment: Here The timing is a little longer & the paragraph too [new JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DWZQ7/6/) try to hover & take away while it is sliding down

Comment: @csh I see what you mean, give me a couple of minutes to fiddle around with my answer :)

Comment: @csh Im not really sure what your after, perhaps this? http://jsfiddle.net/DWZQ7/10/

Comment: I will explain better the outcome I'm looking for. Once you hover on the shown div the hidden div should be sliding down even if the mouse moves away, which I had that with my initial code. The problem I had was that if I move the mouse a bit while it's sliding down (which usually happens) the sliding div goes up & down again, there is now time to see what it is inside the div.

Comment: This is not the right answer but fills my purpose [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DWZQ7/14/).